# Stats.SE favicon bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, favicon

The new SE 2.0 favicons look great—or at least all of them do except for Stats.SE.

The site is trying to load its icon from

```
http://sstatic.net/statsimg/favicon.ico
```

while it's actually at

```
http://sstatic.net/stats/img/favicon.ico
```

Looks to me like a little typo in need of fixing…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good catch, fixed